# Allow parent site of iFrame to be a referral in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My website is advertised through various magazine websites.  One in particular "links" to us by showing their website, a very brief header, and then our website displayed within an iFrame on their website.

In Google Analytics, we don't see this traffic at all as a "referral", so I don't see anything indicating that this traffic is from a 3rd party website.  Is there anything we can do to track page views, etc. that originate not from our website, but actually from the magazine's iFrame?

Edit 1: Just an FYI, Im not looking to necessarily make the parent's site traffic list as a referral in GA.  Merely, if there was any way for me to track this information and tell that the site traffic was coming from the parent site would be helpful to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if your page is being loaded in an iframe or not.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t) for how to do that.

By doing this, you could then send a `custom variable` to GA which says if a user came from within an iframe or not.  That would not tell you which specific iframe it came from, just how many users saw your site from within a frame.

If you want more accurate data about a specific site, you are probably best just asking them to link to your page with a `custom campaign parameter` added to the URL, which allows you to identify traffic from that site.